# onResume not called after recreate in Activity

Tags: android, onresume, onactivityresult, recreate

I'm calling `recreate` in `onActivityResult` of `MainActivity` when certain changes are made in the app settings. After recreation, `onResume` is not called.

I'm also getting the error:

```
E/ActivityThread: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844112/runtimeexception-performing-pause-of-activity-that-is-not-resumed) question, I understood that this function can't be called from `onResume`. But I'm calling them from `onActivityResult`. Also using handler to call `recreate` resolves the problem, but causes a blink that looks bad to the user. What could be the possibly wrong here? How can I use `recreate` without a `Handler`?

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Put some code so that people can actually help you.

Comment: What should I put in here? I thought the problem was well defined enough.

Comment: Put the code of the OnActivityResult here

Comment: I'm just checking the requestcode and resultcode and calling recreate there.

Answer (score 3):

OnActivityResult() is called before onResume(). What you can do is set a flag in the OnActivityResult() that you can check in the onResume() and if the flag is true you can recreate the activity.

What you could actually do is to finish the activity and start the same one, isntead of recreating it. You will get the same effect. it could be something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {

private boolean shouldRecreate = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("AG", "onCreate() called");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (shouldRecreate){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 0){
        shouldRecreate = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What kind of flag should I check? Could you give an example?

Comment: make your own flag, something like shouldRecreate (bool). In the OnActivityResult() you set the shouldRecreate to true if the condition is the one that you want. Then in the onResume you check shouldRecreate == true, if yes, you call the recreate method.

Comment: I set the flag in onActivityResult and checked it in onResume. The error is still coming.

Comment: Make sure set false to shouldRecreate if its true. So that whenevr onresume called .it will not be called  again.

Comment: Ok, but the it should not show the error for the first time atleast. But it is still showing.

Comment: I set shouldRecreate false after first time. Error still coming.

Comment: Use the handler to make a delay (As in the answer you gave in your question), it seems that this is the only solution for that so far, the super.onResume needs a bit of time to finish and that is why you get this error when you try to recreate the activity imidietly.. But you can still use the way with the flag to see if you need to recreate the activity. Check edit for alternate solution!

Comment: Yes. This takes me to base zero. Your method should be working. I don't know why the error still comes.

Comment: I've tried finishing and starting. Gives the same error.

Comment: Thanks for helping anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by sending a broadcast from the `SettingsActivity` to the `BroadcastReciever` in the `MainActivity` and calling `recreate()` inside `onRecieve()`.

Comment: Glad you fixed it :)