# OnCreate method keeps calling OnResume method

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate, onresume

So i have this app and everytime i start the main activity the `OnResume` method gets called.i have put a `Toast` message in both the `OnCreate` and `OnResume` methods and everytime i start the `Activity` both `Toasts` show. Is there something i am missing here? I have looked at the code line by line but found nothing that might be causing this.

Comment: `OnResume` will get called when app get started.

Comment: Ok i didn't know that thank you... But the problem is i wanted to call recreate() on the onResume method when i do that the app just keeps looping between onCreate and onResume methods

Comment: what is recreate function does?

Comment: Take a look at the android lifecycle 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: @JohnJoe, it will recreate the activity, basically call oncreate once again.

Comment: recreate() recreates the activity its a built in method

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35563992/5156075

Answer (score 2):

OnResume() is called everytime in the lifecycle of an activity.
See the picture below.
Add onResume() only when you need to do some task if app is to started from background or from paused state.
[image]

Comment: Ok but i wanna call recreate() on the onResume method which will call onCreate and that calls onResume again which will just be a loop.any alternative solutions?

Comment: What do you want to achieve in recreate? Load the UI , refresh the data or anything else in particular?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some condition and call recreate only if that condition is satisfied. assign a boolean variable if your condition is satisfied and call recreate if this boolean is true or false as per your condition, Otherwise your loop will never stop.

```
private boolean isCheck = false;
onCreate() {
    if(somecondition == true) {
        isCheck = true;
    }
}

onResume() {
    if(!isCheck){
        recreate();
    }
}
```